# Getting the number ordinal with Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

Is it possible to get a number's ordinal with Moment.js? For example if I pass in the number 7 and Momentjs would return '7th'

So far I have tried all these but none have worked

```
console.log(moment("12", "D Do")); // returns n {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "12", _f: "D Do", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
                console.log(moment("3", "D Do")); // returns n {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "3", _f: "D Do", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
                console.log(moment(3).format("D Do")); // returns '1 1st'
                console.log(moment('3').format("D Do")); // returns '1 1st'
                console.log(moment().day('3').format("Do")); // returns '9th'
                console.log(moment().day(3).format("D Do")); // returns '9 9th'
```

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I am trying to process a date. So I get the date in this format DD-MM-YYYY. So if the date is 07-12-2015, I want to display it as 7th.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think Moment.js provides such an interface because it's use case is very limited.

If you don't have a date (e.g. a ranking) you could use the following:

```
function ordinal(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
    case 21:
      return number + 'st';
      break;
    case 2:
    case 22:
      return number + 'nd';
      break;
    case 3:
    case 23:
      return number + 'rd';
      break;
    default:
      return number + 'th';
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: Answer to the edited question:

You can do the following:

```
const date = '3-12-2015';
moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('Do');
```

**[Demo](https://tonicdev.com/juliusrickert/566b0078c1a7f00d00d0e921)**

**Documentation**:

Parse: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Display: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Cool - thanks for the reply- I actually have something like this (although yours is cleaner) in place. I was hoping it was possible with Momentjs.

Comment: Actually - yes, it is part of a date. The date format is like this 30-11-2015. But I only want to display '30th' I will update my question

Comment: Any idea how to get this for (polish) other languages

Comment: Nice easy to read function. It does need to inlcide 31 in the switch statement though. As written this will output "31th".

Answer (score 21):

```
moment.localeData().ordinal(23)
```

---

```
// 23rd
```

Answer (score 17):

Building off of the accepted answer above, you can avoid adding the day to an arbitrary date and instead just do:

`moment('3', 'DD').format('Do');`

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, the above answer will return an invalid date for any number above `30`, so a more stable solution that includes the `31st` would be:

`` moment(`2012-10-${day}`).format('Do') ``

Comment: This will yield `Invalid date` for e.g. the 31st.  An alternative not susceptible might be `moment(\`2012-10-${day}\`).format('Do')`

Comment: How to handle this when date is passed as an argument ?? can you replace the static value with dynamic and give a small code snippet ?